# How can spark-shell work without installing Scala beforehand?

Tags: apache-spark

I have downloaded Spark 1.2.0 (pre-built for Hadoop 2.4). In its quick start doc, it says:

> It is available in either Scala or Python.

What confuses me is that my computer doesn't have Scala installed separately before (OS X 10.10), but when I type `spark-shell` it works well, and the output shows:

```
Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25)
```

as depicted in the screenshot:

[image]

I didn't install any Scala distribution before.

How can spark-shell run without Scala?

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr** Scala binaries are included in Spark already (to make Spark users' life easier).

Under **Downloading** in [Spark Overview](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) you can read about what is required to run Spark:

> Spark runs on both Windows and UNIX-like systems (e.g. Linux, Mac OS).
>   It’s easy to run locally on one machine — all you need is to have java
>   installed on your system PATH, or the JAVA_HOME environment variable
>   pointing to a Java installation.
>
> Spark runs on Java 6+ and Python 2.6+. For the Scala API, Spark 1.2.0
>   uses Scala 2.10. You will need to use a compatible Scala version
>   (2.10.x).

Answer (score 1):

Scala program, including spark-shell, is compiled to Java byte code, which can be run with Java virtual machine (JVM). Therefore, as long as you have JVM installed, meaning `java` command, you can run the Spark-related tools written in Scala.

Comment: Actually, the **spark-shell** can be just the same with raw **scalar  shell**. If so,  what is behind the **spark-shell** ? just *JVM* or *JDK* ?

Comment: It's working in JVM. You can confirm it by looking at the shell scripts: "spark-shell" and "spark-submit". BTW it's "Scala", not scalar.